# Establish interface between ROS and Matlab toolbox files(dll and header)

Tags: ros, matlab, linux, winros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

currently, i have a robot(articulated 6dof arm)(not listed yet in ros supported robots, anywhere) which came with some dll and header files. as per their(robot provider) package description, all we have to do is to copy those files in appropriate folders of matlab installation(windows system) and we get standard commands to operate robot through matlab(with their standard functions).

so the problem is, how can i do it in ubuntu(linux system)? what i mean is, how can i operate the robot through ros? let us assume i have written all the necessary code to talk with this system(let us say in c++ or python), how can i make interface with those robot package files?

initially i thought about copying those dlls in linux matlab installation but later i understood, thats not possible.
i also thought(and read) about using winros and winelib...but how can i do it?(what i mean is these are emulated systems, then how can they communicate with the ros running on ubuntu?)

is anybody have "EXPERIENCE" with this kind of stuff? please share...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216361/establish-interface-between-ros-and-matlab-toolbox-files(dll-and-header)/) by [baiju](https://answers.ros.org/users/22012/baiju/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2015-08-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have found it. from matlab 2015a onwards, mathworks have included ros support into main matlab package.

---

Originally posted by [baiju](https://answers.ros.org/users/22012/baiju/) with karma: 71 on 2015-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0